# How to make an editable SWT combo which allows user to type only the items in the combo

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have an SWT `Combo` wherein I have some list of strings set as items of `Combo`.

The Combo should be editable in such a way that :

1. when user enters a non existing item, it should not be allowed to type and
2. when user enters an existing item, it should prompt based on the each key typed.

Please let me know your suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an example here:

http://my.oschina.net/uniquejava/blog/87573

I modified it slightly so it clears the `Combo` if no match was found:

```
private static String[] items   = new String[] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    Combo combo = new Combo(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        combo.add(items[i]);
    }

    addAutoCompleteFeature(combo);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}

public static void addAutoCompleteFeature(Combo combo)
{
    // Add a key listener
    combo.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
    {
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent)
        {
            Combo cmb = ((Combo) keyEvent.getSource());
            setClosestMatch(cmb);
        }

        // Move the highlight back by one character for backspace
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent)
        {
            if (keyEvent.keyCode == SWT.BS)
            {
                Combo cmb = ((Combo) keyEvent.getSource());
                Point pt = cmb.getSelection();
                cmb.setSelection(new Point(Math.max(0, pt.x - 1), pt.y));
            }
        }

        private void setClosestMatch(Combo combo)
        {
            String str = combo.getText();
            String[] cItems = combo.getItems();
            // Find Item in Combo Items. If full match returns index
            int index = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < cItems.length; i++)
            {
                if (cItems[i].toLowerCase().startsWith(str.toLowerCase()))
                {
                    index = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (index != -1)
            {
                Point pt = combo.getSelection();
                combo.select(index);
                combo.setText(cItems[index]);
                combo.setSelection(new Point(pt.x, cItems[index].length()));
            }
            else
            {
                combo.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}
```